# rails polymorpic assoications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have two models, Doctors and Videos.  Videos are polymorphic and can belong to other models as well (the other models are irrelvant for this question).

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos, :as => :recordable
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recordable, :polymorphic => true  
end
```

I'm playing around in IRB to understand how to get what I want and I am confused trying to get what I am looking for.

```
a = Doctor.last
Video.create(recordable: a)
Video.last.recordable => #this gives me the doctor that I want
```

The commands above work the way I expect, however this doesn't...

```
a.videos => #just gives me an empty array
a.recordable => #undefined method `recordable'
```

Any idea on how I can get the videos associated with a doctor?

Comment: Have you read the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations ?

Comment: yes, it shows how to setup your models but not a lot on how to retrieve those associations.  Unless I am missing something.  Also, I was missing a line that in the model example that I just fixed

Comment: In the documentation, there are 2 models as like yours. So, what's the difference?

Comment: Your models are set up correctly. In your example, `a` is a doctor. Since a doctor has not instance method `#recordable` defined, you're seeing the `NoMethodError`. As for why the `a.videos` call might return an empty array, that could have to do with ActiveRecord caching. Try reloading the doctor with `a.reload` and see if `a.videos` returns the expected result then.

Comment: Ah, I think it was the caching. I reloaded and then the associations were there.  Thank you!

Comment: try a.reload and it will pick them up.  Alternatively, you can has_many: :videos, as: :recordable, inverse_of: :recordable.